# No music, but system sounds works

Tags: music

When I'm playing music on spotify or rythmbox there is no sound. Other sounds (system sounds, movies, youtube) works. I had recently plugged my laptop to TV through HDMI and I noticed that this problem began after unplugging it.
Could anyone help?

Comment: What does your Sound settings screen look like? (Under System Settings.)

Comment: https://s29.postimg.org/5jpk27dgn/Screenshot_from_2017_02_02_11_45_32.png

there is also  rythmbox bar in application its on 100% but still music doesn't play

Comment: If you are using `pulseaudio`, open the audio mixer (via panel plugin or by issuing `pavucontrol` in terminal), and look which output the different input sources are set to (only visible when the application is running).